# File creation in Android

Tags: android, file, creation

Can a xml file be created in Android just by creating an object of File class ie.

```
File FF=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"//new.xml");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(FF);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

or 
is it nececessary to use createNewFile() ie. FF.createNewFile()?

I've not written the detailed code here

Answer (score 0):

Basically this should work if you requested the permission to write on the sd card. Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I personally open (for write) and create the files at once, except I want a 0 byte file for some kinds of checks e.g. as a kind of switch.

Comment: yes it is possible you need to add permission this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I was just searching that line on my mobile. :-)

Comment: Thanks buddy I already added it my question was when do we use createNewFile() when file can be created like this?